# How to populate an array list in a while loop

Tags: java, arraylist, while-loop

My problem is this

```
Scanner sf = new Scanner(f);
ArrayList<String> teamArr = new ArrayList<String>();
int counterPopulate = 0;

while(sf.hasNextLine()){
    teamArr[counterPopulate] = sf.nextLine();
    counterPopulate++;           
}
```

Any solutions, this is surrounded by a try catch. 
Getting the problem at this part `teamArr[counterPopulate] = sf.nextLine();`

Comment: what language is this?

Comment: since `String` is capitalized, it looks like java

Comment: are you getting an `index out of bounds` exception?  if not, what exception are you getting

Comment: @SamIam I don't even think you can run the code the way he's trying to add to the ArrayList

Comment: advise for future questions: please provide an error message if there's one. in this example it's kinda obvious to the professional eye but this information makes it easier to help you with more complex problems

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because `ArrayList` is different than normal `arrays`, you need to use methods of the `ArrayList` class to populate the `ArrayList`.

In your case you need to do:

```
while(sf.hasNextLine()){
            teamArr.add(sf.nextLine());
        }
```

Assuming you're using Java.

Have a look at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html

Answer (score 1):

As you are using `ArrayList<String>`, `add(String value)` method is used to add new `String` Object into the `ArrayList`.

A simple solution of your problem is given below.

assuming that language is JAVA.

```
Scanner sf = new Scanner(f);
ArrayList<String> teamArr = new ArrayList<String>();

while( sf.hasNextLine() ) {
    teamArr.add(sf.nextLine());
}
```

for more details about `ArrayList` and `Collection` please refer :

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html